# IText 7, Text alignment inside a PdfFormField?

Tags: itext7

I have tried and searched for this question but with no luck.

This is what I have tried.

```
using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(template), new 
PdfWriter(newPath)))
{
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(doc, true);

    // Replace form fields with correct data
    form.GetField("Greet").SetValue("Hello world!");    


    // I have tried this to with no luck
    form.GetField("Greet").SetJustification(1).SetValue("Hello World");

    form.FlattenFields();
}
```

Comment: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/changing-the-alignment-of-a-field
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Pdf does not support justification for acro-forms.
So this is not an iText problem. The spec simply doesn't allow it.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as the accepted answer. Since this is really what the spec says :p

Comment: Thx you for quick reply

In the link below:
http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.1/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfFormField.html#setJustification-int-

I found this:
public PdfFormField setJustification(int justification)
Sets a code specifying the form of quadding (justification) to be used in displaying the text: 0 Left-justified 1 Centered 2 Right-justified
Parameters: justification - the value to set the justification attribute to
Returns: the edited field

Reading this make me wonder why  "form.GetField("Greet").SetJustification(1).SetValue("Hello World");" is not centered,

Comment: That's because the formfield (logically) inherits from the component that offers this method. Rather than because we support that method.